# Google Spreadsheet - Perform Random Operation 40 Times and Store Additive Result

Tags: spreadsheet, google-sheets-api

Quick question, I'm using Google Spreadsheet, I put this in a cell.

=If(RANDBETWEEN(1,40)=1,1,0)

Above is the code I use to generate a random number between 1 and 40.  If it happens to land on '1', then it returns '1' to the cell otherwise 0.  I want this loop however to loop lets say '20' times.

So it's possible that a '1' might occur '3' times lets say during the 20 attempts.  I am looking for code that would total up the amount of random occurrences where '1' was outputted and output the value.

So if it occurred '3' times, it would output 3.  If randomly during the loop '1' was triggered '5' times it would return 5 and so forth etc.

How do I do this in Google Spreadsheet?

Comment: copy it 20 times, e.g. into cells A1 to A20. Then use =sum(A1:A20) .. This is not a good place to post things like this, suggest you use the google spreadsheet forum: http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!categories/docs/spreadsheets

Comment: Good idea, I like that, I also posted a solution below, what do you think is faster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I could not find a way through the normal commands, but if you go into the script editor and add the following:

```
function calcRandomTotal(iterations,percentChance){
  var maxNumber = 1/percentChance;
  var hits = 0;
  var randNum = 0;

  for(i=0;i<iterations;i++){
    randNum = randomFromInterval(1,maxNumber);
    if(randNum == 1){
      hits++; 
      randNum = 0;//reset it
    }
  }

  return hits;
};

function randomFromInterval(from,to)
{
    return Math.floor(Math.random()*(to-from+1)+from);
}
```

then simply say = calcRandomTotal(iterations,percentChance) or
calcRandomTotal(20,0.025) (because 0.025 is 2.5% or a 1/40 chance.  This will run the random simulation for a set amount of iterations and return the total result.

Comment: If anyone has a better solution let me know.  The drawback to this is it's a bit slow to calculate

Answer (score 0):

I have found another solution to this without any code!

```
=IFERROR(ArrayFormula(sum(randbetween(0,10)+(row(indirect("A1:A"&(D$125)))*0))),0)
```

The idea is to use array formula and trick it into thinking there is many cells using the indirect function, in my case D$125 refers to a cell for how many times you want to iterate the randbetween.

Enjoy!

Comment: The only flaw to this, is whatever the random number chosen it seems to stick with that for all the iterations.  If someone can improve this concept please do!